# Remove a set of special character from a String

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove a set of special characters (i.e., `[]'?!+-.,`) from a string.
The typical exclusive solution `replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")` is not ok, because I just need to remove those characters, and also save text containing greek characters. For example:

```
public static void test_regex() {
    ArrayList<String> tests = new ArrayList<>();
    tests.add("------.");
    tests.add("+[---].");
    tests.add("------?");
    tests.add("---]〛");
    tests.add("A++[---].");
    tests.add("AV[---]S");

    for (String s : tests) {
        String becomes = s.replaceAll("[.-\\\\,]", "");
        System.out.println(s + " becomes <" + becomes + ">");
    }
}
```

should give as a output

```
------. becomes <>
+[---]. becomes <>
------? becomes <>
---]〛 becomes <>
A++[---]. becomes <A>
AV[---] becomes <AV>
```

But I cant. I succeed to remove `.` and `-` with `[.-]`, but then I add `\\[` and breaks everything (also tried `\\\\[` or `\\\\\\[`) , also the `.` which before worked is not working anymore.

Which way to escape each one of these characters?

Comment: Escape the hyphen. Or always keep it at the start/end of the character class.

Comment: `String becomes = s.replaceAll("[ \\]\\[.\\\\,+?-]+", "");`

Comment: Please @anubhava post it as the answer so I can accept it. That's perfect.

Comment: ok I am reopening the dup because hyphen in the middle is just one part of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following regex replacement to get rid of all unwanted characters:

```
String becomes = s.replaceAll("[ \\]\\[.\\\\,+?-]+", "");
```

- You will need to include all other unwanted characters such as `[, ], +, ?, |` etc in your character class.
- It ie better to use a quantifier `+` here for better performance.
- Remember to place an unescaped hyphen at first or last place in a character class.